# Can't use moredelim in tcolorbox environment listing options

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I've got a `tcolorbox`+`listings`-powered environment for example terminal sessions – I'd like to prefix user input to distinguish it (by color/weight/etc.) from computer output.

Defining the delimiter with `\lstset` works just fine, but I can't use the same definition in `listing options` within a `\newtcblisting`.  Instead, TeX suddenly decides it needs to input a file to feel good about itself.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newif\ifbroken

\brokentrue  % toggle me!

\ifbroken
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{exampleoutput}{
  listing options={
    moredelim=[il][\bfseries]{>>},
  }
}

\else % works just fine

\lstset{moredelim=[il][\bfseries]{>>}}

\fi

\begin{document}

\ifbroken

\begin{exampleoutput}
>>hello
\end{exampleoutput}

\else

\begin{lstlisting}
>>hello
\end{lstlisting}

\fi
\end{document}
```

---

```
ERROR: Package Listings Error: File `[(.tex)' not found.

--- TeX said ---

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: 
./mwe.tex:27: Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.27 \end{exampleoutput}^^M

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

Comment: You have to enclose the `[...]` of the moredelim option with `{...}`, i.e. protect the `optional argument `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[...]` within `moredelim` option must be enclosed with `{...}` to prevent the fragile nature of the option handling (i.e. how `tcolorbox` transports this option to `listings` environments and its optional argument.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\newif\ifbroken

\brokentrue  % toggle me!

\ifbroken
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{exampleoutput}{
  listing options={{
    moredelim=[il][\bfseries]{>>}},
  }
}

\else % works just fine

\lstset{moredelim=[il][\bfseries]{>>}}

\fi

\begin{document}

\ifbroken

\begin{exampleoutput}
>>hello
\end{exampleoutput}

\else

\begin{lstlisting}
>>hello
\end{lstlisting}

\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: I could've sworn I tried that, but question: why? I've only ever seen it necessary (and *understood why*) when it was in an optional argument itself (e.g., `\macro[\opt[arg]]`). Why is it necessary here?

Comment: (And, amazingly, `{\n{` is different than `{{\n` here…)

Comment: @SeanAllred: I used the wrong words: The `listings` env. has an optional argument, passing the `moredelim=....` content to this optional argument will break